# Unable to connect services in ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have two services in ECS with 5 containers each (total 10 containers). All 10 containers are interdependent on each other.

My goal is to make the containers in two services talk to each other.
I am trying to use ECS `service connect` which is configured to use common namespaces in the cluster. I notice the injected proxy sidecar/container in the running task for both the services.

When I curl a route from public ip of service A to another service B I get following error

`upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination`

What possibly can be wrong in the setup?

I am happy to add more information if required.

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting? Is it a name resolution error? A network timeout error? Something else? Please edit your question to include the _exact_ error message in the question itself.

Comment: @MarkB The services are healthy, when I curl the public IP of one task in service A to connect with another container in service B. I get nodejs error. unable to connect.